# How do I implement this If-Else logic in my T-SQL transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design

I have a table like

```
CREATE TABLE FinishedMappings ( 
    partner_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
    survey_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (partner_id,survey_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (partner_id) REFERENCES Partners(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (survey_id) REFERENCES Surveys(id)
);
```

which is supposed track people who've taken a survey. If person `X` hasn't taken survey `Y`, then the `partner_id=X,survey_id=Y` combo isn't in that table. I'm creating a stored procedure that updates based on new information of whether a person has taken a particular survey. How I've started writing it is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateFinishValue (@partner_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
                                    @survey_id INT,
                                    @finished TINYINT)
AS  
    IF [finished is equal to 1 and the @partner_id,@survey_id pair isnt in the FinishedMappings db]
        INSERT INTO FinishedMappings (partner_id,survey_id) VALUES (survey_id,partner_id)
    ELSE
        DELETE FROM FinishedMappings WHERE partner_id=@partner_id AND survey_id=@survey_id
GO
```

but I'm not sure how to implement the

```
[finished is equal to 1 and the @partner_id,@survey_id pair isnt in the FinishedMappings db]
```

part or if there's a more compact way of writing this overall. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
if (@finished = 1 and
    not exists (select 1
                from FinishedMappings fm
                where fm.partner_id = @parner_id and fm.survey_id = @survey_id
               )
   )
begin
    . . .
end;
```

Comment: Is the `then` necessary?

Comment: @SubparWebDev . . . No, it's not even syntactically correct.  But I do *think* "then" when writing such logic ;)